# Why doesn't anyone go over the Calm Belt?

Tags: one-piece

The Calm Belt has no oceanic currents so sailing a normal ship through it is impossible.

However, throughout the series we have seen ships that can sail without wind, such as Boa Hancock's ship that is pulled by sea kings. There are also plenty of Devil Fruit users that have an ability to get them across. A lot of people already travel the sea by themselves using their powers, like Kuzan, who can glide across the water, or even Buffalo that can fly over.

Why hasn't anyone thought to go over the Calm Belt instead of traversing the Grand Line? Is there something that presents that from happening?

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that no one ever crossed the Calm Belts.

First of all, from https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Calm_Belt, we know that Marines used Seastone-lined ships to repel Sea Kings and cross the Calm Belts. Besides numbers, strong admirals, this is certainly one of their strong points, as they can travel fast through the world. Impel Down is in the Calm Belts, so travels there are pretty frequent.

Amazon Lily is in the middle of a Calm Belt, and Rayleigh traveled there by swimming! So powerful individuals can travel there if they want to. As for normal pirates, the Calm Belts is full of Sea Kings and there is no wind to travel by sails, so special boats are needed. This eliminates 99% of pirates.

Finally, there is no proof of this in the manga so far, but fishmen, at least strong enough ones like Arlong or Jinbei, can probably travel easily within the Calm Belts. Also, the Revolutionary Army is scattered through the world, the faction of each sea under the order of one Commander. The commanders meet at the beginning of Wano Country Arc and they seem to have casually traveled through the world. Granted, the revolutionaries are experts in infiltraton so they may have stealthily crossed lands but crossing Calm Belts seems within their reach.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody goes though the calm belt because there is nothing important there and no reason to go there beside to go through the Grand-line. https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Calm_Belt

Comment: I put the link in case if i missed anything have a good day :)

Comment: Well, up until this point it only works as a kind of boundary as you said but could also hold some secrets to it if Oda has plans for it ... Also, Amazon Lily and a couple of other islands are found in the Calm Belt so you can't say there is nothing important :)

Comment: I can't say your wrong :)